# Power source event trigger

Tags: sleep-wake, ups

Late 2014 Mac mini running Sierra connected to an APC BackUPS Pro 900. No special software has been installed to support the UPS.

At the moment I run `pmset` every minute to determine the power source, and trigger actions based on the results.

However, a dialog window pops up as soon as the Mac switches to backup power. I'm wondering if there is any way I can trigger based on anything else, given that macOS seems to be able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using third party tools, like Power Manager, you can [trigger scripts based on your UPS state](https://dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-09-18-ups-scripting-on-mac-os-x/).

[image: Power Manager used to script a shut down when 30% of UPS left]

Thirty party tools can monitor the UPS state through the `IOKit` and receive callbacks on state changes; thus avoiding polling.

If you are comfortable with shell script or AppleScript, Power Manager provides hooks for [scripting your UPS](https://dssw.co.uk/blog/2013-06-23-scripting-batteries-and-ups-on-mac-os-x/) in these languages.

I wrote Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions.

Comment: That is some serious scripting support. Appreciate the recommendation. However, it's not worth it for me to make this investment in software. I might see if I can build a simple command line tool using IOKit, thanks for that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

In `System Preferences > Energy Saver`, you will find an additional tab labeled UPS, which allows you to set specific Shutdown Options...

[image]

Comment: Using that, thanks. But I want to run custom scripts that trigger when power switches to UPS and back to grid.